# Python reference count and ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes, reference-counting

Hallo,

I have some troubles understanding the python reference count.
What I want to do is return a tuple from c++ to python using the ctypes module.

C++:

```
PyObject* foo(...)
{

  ...
  return Py_BuildValue("(s, s)", value1, value2);
}
```

Python:

```
pointer = c_foo(...) # c_foo loaded with ctypes
obj = cast(pointer, py_object).value
```

I'm was not sure about the ref count of obj, so I tried `sys.getrefcount()`
 and got `3`. I think it should be `2` (the `getrefcount` functions makes one ref itself).

Now I can't make `Py_DECREF()` before the return in C++ because the object gets deleted. Can I decrease the ref count in python?

***edit***
What happens to the ref count when the cast function is called? I'm not really sure from the documentation below. http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.cast

> ctypes.cast(obj, type)
>      This function is similar to the cast operator in C. It returns a new instance of type which points to the same memory block as obj. type must be a pointer type, and obj must be an object that can be interpreted as a pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On further research I found out that one can specify the return type of the function.
http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions
This makes the cast obsolete and the ref count is no longer a problem.

```
clib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('some.so')
c_foo = clib.c_foo
c_foo.restype = ctypes.py_object
```

As no additional answers were given I accept my new solution as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your c++ code seems to be a classic wrapper using the [official C-API](http://docs.python.org/c-api/) and it's a bit weird since ctypes is usually used for using classic c types in python (like int, float, etc...).

I use personnally the C-API "alone" (without ctypes) but on my personnal experience, you don't have to worry about the reference counter in this case since you are returning a native python type with `Py_BuildValue`. When a function returns an object, the **ownership** of the returned object is given to the calling function.

You have to worry about `Py_XINCREF`/`Py_XDECREF` (better than `Py_INCREF`/`Py_DECREF` because it accepts NULL pointers) only when you want to change ownership of the object :

For example, you have created a wrapper of a map in python (let's call the typed object py_map). The element are of c++ class Foo and you have created an other python wrapper for them (let's call it py_Foo). If you create a function that wrap the [] operator, you are going to return a py_Foo object in python :

```
F = py_Map["key"]
```

but since the ownership is given to the calling function, you will call the destructor when you delete `F` and the map in c++ contains a pointer to a deallocated objet !

The solution is to write in c++ in the wrapper of [] :

```
...
PyObject* result; // My py_Foo object
Py_XINCREF(result); // transfer the ownership
return result;
}
```

You should take a look at the notion of [borrowed and owned reference](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ext/refcountsInPython.html) in python. This is essential to understand properly the reference counter.

Comment: But you create a python-c module right? I wanted to skip that and with ctypes you can just `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('some.so')`. So the return type handling is different. With ctypes it's `ctypes.py_object`. Then I use the cast function and I'm not sure how the ref count is handled correctly. See my edit.

Comment: Yes indeed, that may be a bit more complicated... I tried to read the code source of cast() but I hadn't enough time to investiagte properly. I will try to take a look when I'll have enough time and edit my answer if I find something that prove that ctypes takes the ownership (if it's the case, maybe you should consider creating directly a python-c object to eliminate these problems. That's quite easy since you are already working with PyObject)